BasicTextField cursor color remains black in Dark Mode. How to change it?
I've tried using OutlinedTextField or simple TextField, but I found out that the padding is too large. And no matter what I did, it just wouldn't shrink.
So I use BasicTextField with smaller padding like this:
BasicTextField(
    modifier = modifier,
    value = value,
    keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    textStyle = textStyle,
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        if (value.isEmpty()) placeholder()
        innerTextField()
    }
)

But then the problem is, that when the user sets dark background, the cursor color stays black. I've modified the text color so that it can be readable, but cursor color is still black.


The selection color and cursor color thus is not visible.
Is there any way I can make it visible? I am using Material 1.7.2 right now.
Thank you
EDIT:
I've tried to add CompositionLocalProvider, but it didn't work either. The cursor color is still black.
val colors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary.copy(dimming),
    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary.copy(dimming)
)
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides colors) {
    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = value,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        textStyle = textStyle,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            if (value.isEmpty()) placeholder()
            innerTextField()
        }
    )
}

This is when I add colors parameter:

EDIT 2:
I've found out why the cursor won't change according to the theme.
In the source code, here:
https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.foundation/foundation/1.0.0-beta01-source/androidx/compose/foundation/text/BasicTextField.kt.html
the cursorBrush is hard coded to black if left empty. There is no other default color. Therefore you must specify cursorBrush color if you want to change it to other than black since it won't follows your theme.kt colors.
@Composable
fun BasicTextField(
    value: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = if (singleLine) 1 else Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    cursorBrush: Brush = SolidColor(Color.Black),
    decorationBox: @Composable (innerTextField: @Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit =
        @Composable { innerTextField -> innerTextField() }
)


I recommend not hard coding colors; instead, allow theme.kt to manage the colors based on the app's dark or light mode.
After reviewing documentation of BasicTextField accepts cursorbrush parameter for setting cursor color,
Therefore, in cursorBrush argument, pass in your colorScheme like this
cursorBrush = SolidColor(colorScheme.primary)

Also I want to clarify that
1.decorationBox parameter is not meant for setting cursor color. How it works is that it decorates around the actualTextfield, you can verify this in the layout inspector

Our actual textfield which takes the input and displays the same, Notice the cursor color, my primary theme colour is green

Without the decorator, text appears on the background like this

in layout inspector

2.It's asking you to call innerTextField inside a composable i.e Box
in our case
Here is a template:
BasicTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = colorScheme.onSurface), // Using theme color for text
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
                decorationBox = { actualTextField ->
                    Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(colorScheme.surface, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)) // Using theme color for background of the textbox
                                    .padding(8.dp)
                       ) {
                        actualTextField()
                    }
                },
                cursorBrush = SolidColor(colorScheme.primary),//define cursor color here
                      )

As per docs its innerTextField , but for your understanding I have used actualTextField
Preview of the Behaviour and appearance of the template code:


Yes, I don't hardcode colors, and I've tried to add cursorBrush or colors. Everytime I add color in any way, decorationBox gives me an error message noting that it cannot infer innerTextField type.

The parameter seems a little bit different. There is no TextFieldDefaults.color(), so I use TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()

Decorationbox parameter has nothing to do with cursor colour.Upon looking up the documentation there is a cursorBrush: Brush, parameter try tinkering with it. Im away from workstation I'll update my answer once I  check it out.

And your error means that kotlin auto infer is not able to figure out the type. I.e suppose val num=5, kotlin auto infers that it's an integer datatype, and it interpret it as val num:Int= 5. So basically it's telling it's not able to 'infer' that num is an Int, so you have to "explicitly" specify the type as as :Inti.e val num:Int=5 

Yes, that is why I found it rather strange. When I removed cursorBrush and colors, decorationBox gave no error. I could remove decorationBox, but then it would display nothing. Just an empty box whenever I type anything. I'll try to force innerTextField as @Composable () -> Unit,

@Magician I have verified that the params work and also clarified your doubt about decoration params, hope this clears your doubts.Feel free to ask for more clarifications

innerTextField error was due to that BasicTextField has no colors parameter. So cursorBrush works. Thank you
